# Improve tuple distance computation algorithm for time efficiency

Tags: python, algorithm, list, distance, point

I have an algorithm that computes the distance of every point `p` (my coordinate value represented in a tuple) to every other tuple in my list of tuples.

Lists of points:

```
centerList = [(54, 2991),
            (1717, 2989),
            (1683, 2991),
            (1604, 2991),
            (114, 2991),
            (919,222),
            (930,233)]
```

Distance functoin:

```
def getDistance(p0, p1):
    return math.sqrt((p0[0] - p1[0])**2 + (p0[1] - p1[1])**2)
```

Algorithm for computing the distance of point `p` to every other point in the list of tuples.

```
i = 0
distanceList = []
for p in range(len(centerList)):
    while i < len(centerList):
        print centerList[p], centerList[i], getDistance(centerList[p], centerList[i])
        distance = getDistance(centerList[p], centerList[i])
        if distance < 20:
            distanceList.append(distance)
        i += 1
    i = p + 2
```

My current algorithm increments in a way that isn't redundant but in its current state its too brute for a realistic application. My problem lies in the fact that my actual `centerList` contains thousands of tuples.

What can be done to improve the time efficiency of this tuple comparison algorithm?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to compute the distance between every pair of points. This is inherently O(n^2), so you might want to parallelize this

Comment: you could drop the sqrt for starters.

Comment: There's something broken in your algorithm I guess. `distance = getDistance(centerList[p], centerList[i])` the first iteration compares `centerList[0]` and `centerlist[0]`. This doesn't take place for the subsequent iterations where `i` will be `i = p + 2` . 1st  iter: `getDistance(centerList[0], centerList[0])`, second iter: `getDistance(centerList[1], centerList[2])`... Why? Mathematically speaking, comparing a distance from the same point is zero. That's if x and y and distances where x=y then the distance from x to y is zero.

Comment: Yup, good catch. That's why I run `if distance < 20 and distance > 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could combine [`sklearn.metrics.euclidean_distances`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances.html) with `numpy`'s boolean indexing to do the computation:

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics import euclidean_distances
>>> import numpy as np
>>> centerList = np.array(centerList)
>>> distances = euclidean_distances(centerList)
>>> distances[distances<20]
array([  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,   0.        ,  15.55634919,  15.55634919,   0.        ])
```

The computation of the distances uses numpy's matrix algebra developed in high-speed C. The docs also emphasize the efficiency of the underlying math technique:

> For efficiency reasons, the euclidean distance between a pair of row
>   vector x and y is computed as:
>
> ```
> dist(x, y) = sqrt(dot(x, x) - 2 * dot(x, y) + dot(y, y))
> ```
>
> This formulation has two advantages over other ways of computing
>   distances. First, it is computationally efficient when dealing with
>   sparse data. Second, if one argument varies but the other remains
>   unchanged, then dot(x, x) and/or dot(y, y) can be pre-computed.

Comment: @DaOnlyOwner Not a question of complexity, more of CPU runtime.

Comment: Works great! Is there a way I can remove one of these tuples from `centerList` if the distance is less than 20 using this approach?

Comment: It takes two to tango. One coordinate might have a distance less than 20 with one, and have a distance greater than 20 with another.

Answer (score 0):

With `numpy` only:

```
import numpy

centerList = [(54, 2991), (1717, 2989), (1683, 2991), (1604, 2991), (114, 2991), (919,222), (930,233)]
centerList = numpy.array(centerList)

def getDistance(p0,p1):
    return numpy.linalg.norm(p0-p1)
```

Will return the same results as your `getDistance` function.